# javascript - how would you write the if(...) statement for selection options in a form?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, selection

How do you write the `if` statement for a select option using javascript?

I wrote a form and made a select option list. I want to write an `if` statement that will do something if an option is selected.

**JS**

```
function name(obj) {
    if (option.value == "cat") {
        document.getElementById("owner").jim.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>
    selection:*
    <select id="Sone" name="Selection" size="1">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="cat" onclick="name(this);">cat</option>
        <option value="dog" onclick="name(this);">dog</option>
        <option value="bird" onclick="name(this);">bird</option>
        <option value="Other" onclick="name(this);">Other</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: function name(obj)
{
 if (option.value == "cat")
  {
     document.getElementById("owner").jim.disabled=true ;
     
  }       
 }

Comment: <p>selection:* 
<select id= "Sone" name="Selection" size="1">
<option>Select</option>
<option value="cat" onclick="name(this);">cat</option>
<option value="dog" onclick="name(this);">dog</option>
<option value="bird" onclick="name(this);">bird</option>
<option value="Other" onclick="name(this);">Other</option>
</select></p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select id= "Sone" name="Selection" onchange="check()">
<option value="cat">cat</option> 
<option value="dog">dog</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="res" size="25"/>
```

And the  function is :-

```
function check() {
 var val = document.getElementById('Sone').value;
 if(val=='cat') {
  document.getElementById('res').value = "Thanks for selecting cat";
 } else {
  document.getElementById('res').value = "please select CAT";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to work as below

```
   <form name="AddEditUser">
   .
   .
   <select name="listCompany"  style="width:200px"  id="listCompany" onchange="fnCompany()">
   <option value="None">None</option>
   <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
   <option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
   </select>

   </form>
```

You have to call the javascript function a

```
 function fnCompany(){

   if(document.frmAddEditUser.listCompany.value=='None'){
      //do something
   }
 }
```